# What services are available for managing a product roadmap?

Tags: agile, product-management, roadmaps

I'm not fully versed in project management but this seemed like a good place to ask the question. I'm looking to manage a "product roadmap" for a web site and eventually a mobile app. I'd like to be able to break things down to specific tasks and also have a method to get feedback from both users of the service and non-technical people on the team. What I'm trying to do is pretty much similar to 'agile' programming but, again, I'd like to include non-technical aspects to the process. Most agile interfaces would likely turn-off any non-technical users.

It would be great to have project management, specific task management, documentation, bug reporting, and feedback all wrapped up in one service. Are there any existing services that anyone can recommend? Currently I have to cobble together everything from different services. I've used Basecamp, Beanstalk, and Confluence. Also took a look at Solve360 but it seems more a CRM application.

Comment: In the current form this is off-topic as you're asking for tool recommendations. However, the question on how to build a roadmap would be on topic.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the limitations on tool discussions but I'll keep that in mind. - Bob

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking up the [GO (goal orientated) roadmap by Roman Pilcher](http://www.romanpichler.com/tools/product-roadmap/). He makes the template available as a free download.

Your choice in tool is unlikely to help you building a better road map. Often roadmaps go into too much details (specific tasks) rather than keeping the planning at a strategic level. This is a common problem across many teams.

Hope this helps

Comment: Will, thanks for the link. I found it very helpful. I was hoping to get away from printed, paper forms or spreadsheets but Roman Pilcher's templates are a great way for me to start. - Bob